# In rustc_ast, how to match TokenStream (an abstract sequence of tokens)

Tags: rust, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree

I work with [rustc_ast::tokenstream::TokenStream](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nightly-rustc/rustc_ast/tokenstream/struct.TokenStream.html)

I printed the TokenStream in console:

```
Contents of value2.tokens: TokenStream(
    [
        Token(
            Token {
                kind: Ident(
                    "dead_code",
                    false,
                ),
                span: src/main.rs:12:9: 12:18 (#0),
            },
            Alone,
        ),
    ],
)
```

I need to match on this TokenStream to make sure we deal with "dead_code" attributes-symbol (and not some other symbol)

Below is piece of code where I am dealing with AST and trying to match TokenStream, please pay attention to comments in the code, where I stuck *// THIS MATCH IS NOT CORRECT, HOW TO MATCH HERE?*

```
for attr in tcx.get_attrs(item.owner_id.to_def_id(), sym::allow) {
                println!("Print attributes: {:#?}", attr);
                if let AttrKind::Normal(value) = &attr.kind {
                    if let AttrArgs::Delimited(value2) = &value.item.args {
                        if let value3 = &value2.tokens {
                            println!("Contents of value2.tokens: {:#?}", value3);
                            match value3 {
                                [a] => { // THIS MATCH IS NOT CORRECT, HOW TO MATCH HERE?
                                    println!("hi, {}", a)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I tried to match insides of this TokenStream as tuple, enum, list... all wouldn't work. I face types mismatch all the time.

I tried to use [this parser](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/5133e154590991203c84702ef59482f729b19bbf/compiler/rustc_expand/src/base.rs#L1305), but failed, because of it's complexity.

So how to match a TokenStream which is an abstract sequence of tokens?

Comment: Are you sure you're working with rustc's `TokenStream` and not https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/proc_macro/struct.TokenStream.html? It seems unlikely unless you're extending rustc.

Comment: I work on [coq-of-rust project](https://github.com/formal-land/coq-of-rust/). 

Goal is to translate `Rust` code to `Coq` code (final goal is formal verification of any rust code with `Coq`)

Problem: if in `Rust` code we have an attribute #[allow(dead_code)] on top of `Struct`  then in `Coq` translation we should show comment: `marked as "dead code"`.

Comment: So from the HIR AST I can catch that `Struct` in rust source code is having `allow` attribute, by using `has_attr` like this `tcx.has_attr(item.owner_id.to_def_id(), sym::allow)`,

on the next step I use `get_attrs` and then I go through AST... trying to reach what I need. I successfully match AST, but when I face TokenStream - I can not match it. And `dead_code` is inside this TokenStream.

Comment: and one of problems is that inside TokenStream field is private, so I can not get it like this: `value3.0.iter().enumerate().peekable();
    |                                                  ^ private field

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0616`.`

Comment: So I am reading [this source code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nightly-rustc/src/rustc_ast/tokenstream.rs.html#305) for ideas on how to match `TokenStream`. I am new to Rust.

Comment: As for `proc_macro`: [source code's documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nightly-rustc/src/rustc_ast/tokenstream.rs.html#305) says: it's similar to `proc_macro::Spacing`, but for tokens.

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to do it!

Using [method trees()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nightly-rustc/rustc_ast/tokenstream/struct.TokenStream.html#method.trees) helped me,
and then [function look_ahead](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nightly-rustc/rustc_ast/tokenstream/struct.RefTokenTreeCursor.html#method.look_ahead) should be used.

This is the solution code:

```
for attr in tcx.get_attrs(item.owner_id.to_def_id(), sym::allow) {
                println!("Print attributes: {:#?}", attr);
                if let AttrKind::Normal(value) = &attr.kind {
                    if let AttrArgs::Delimited(value2) = &value.item.args {
                        if let value3 = &value2.tokens {
                            println!("Contents of value2.tokens (my TokenStream): {:#?}", value3);
                            let into_trees = &value3.trees();
                            let continue_try = into_trees.look_ahead(0);
                            match continue_try {
                                Some(res) => {
                                    if let rustc_ast::tokenstream::TokenTree::Token(res2, _) = res {
                                        if let rustc_ast::token::TokenKind::Ident(a, _) = res2.kind
                                        {
                                            println!("Result here! {:#?}", a.as_str())
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                _ => println!("Ain't special"),
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```